# Using Socks 4/5 proxy in Java?

Tags: java, socks

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(Action.proxies.get(1), 3128));

try{
    url = new URL(formattedURL);

    connection = url.openStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    connection));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line !=null){
        response.append(line.replace("<br/>","\n").replace("<p>", "\n"));
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    connection.close();
} catch(final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see, I've created an object at the top which gets a proxy from the HashMap I added data into.

How do I use the proxy so that when the connection is made with `url.openStream()` it uses the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`URL.openConnection(Proxy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28java.net.Proxy%29) followed by [`URLConnection.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Comment: That can only be done with URLConnection, I'm not using URLConnect           import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

Comment: @user2756300: well, `URL.openConnection()` returns an `URLConnection`. In fact the JavaDoc for `URL.openStream()` tells you that it's simply a shortcut for `URL.openConnection().getInputStream()`.

Comment: There seems to be an error when I run my program: http://pastebin.com/ZxfHg9Lc                                             that is the code here is the error: http://pastebin.com/WCenkP3r

Comment: @user2756300: first of all, that's a trivial NPE, you should be able to figure it out on your own (check the pointed-to-line number). Second, that does not seem to be a benign use of proxies. Switching proxies after x bad logins, and trying several username:password combinations is not something that you'd need to do if you respected a sites TOS (and/or the law).

Comment: I'm trying to make a Mod for a game that allows you to get 5 times to login before it changes the proxy. I don't know what you mean by Trival NPE, so if you could please help me out on this one, it would be much appreciated. Thanks